# Efficient data structure for fast random access, search, insertion and deletion

Tags: arrays, data-structures, list, linked-list

I'm looking for a data structure (or structures) that would allow me keep me an ordered list of integers, no duplicates, with indexes and values in the same range.

I need four main operations to be efficient, in rough order of importance:

1. taking the value from a given index
2. finding the index of a given value
3. inserting a value at a given index
4. deleting a value at a given index

Using an array I have 1 at O(1), but 2 is O(N) and insertion and deletions are expensive (O(N) as well, I believe).

A Linked List has O(1) insertion and deletion (once you have the node), but 1 and 2 are O(N) thus negating the gains.

I tried keeping two arrays a[index]=value and b[value]=index, which turn 1 and 2 into O(1) but turn 3 and 4 into even more costly operations.

Is there a data structure better suited for this?

Comment: Shouldn't really matter, but it's C++

Comment: It does matter; not all languages offer the same data structures. For instance, this particular problem could be solved very efficiently by a C Judy array or a C# CPTrie. (Or, of course, some kind of balanced binary tree as Ayman suggested.)

Comment: The question doesn't really make sense: if you have an *ordered* list of integers, what does it mean to insert a value at a given index? If it's ordered there is only one position where it could logically be inserted.

Similarly, if there are no duplicates, then you can't delete a value at a particular index, since there is only 1 index where the value can be.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would use a [red-black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree) to map keys to values. This gives you O(log(n)) for 1, 3, 4. It also maintains the keys in sorted order.

For 2, I would use a hash table to map values to keys, which gives you O(1) performance. It also adds O(1) overhead for keeping the hash table updated when adding and deleting keys in the red-black tree.

Comment: i knew i read that somewhere: http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~wein/publications/pdfs/rb_tree.pdf

Comment: @Javier: Red-black trees absolutely do not have amortized O(1) access. Red-black trees do not actually *do* anything when you read an element in the tree, so there's no amortization.

No binary tree, dynamic or no, can achieve o(n log n) for accessing n arbitrary elements in the tree.

Answer (score 4):

How about using a sorted array with binary search?

Insertion and deletion is slow. but given the fact that the data are plain integers could be optimized with calls to memcpy() if you are using C or C++. If you know the maximum size of the array, you can even avoid any memory allocations during the usage of the array, as you can preallocate it to the maximum size.

The "best" approach depends on how many items you need to store and how often you will need to insert/delete compared to finding. If you rarely insert or delete a sorted array with O(1) access to the values is certainly better, but if you insert and delete things frequently a binary tree can be better than the array. For a small enough n the array most likely beats the tree in any case.

If storage size is of concern, the array is better than the trees, too. Trees also need to allocate memory for every item they store and the overhead of the memory allocation can be significant as you only store small values (integers).

You may want to profile what is faster, the copying of the integers if you insert/delete from the sorted array or the tree with it's memory (de)allocations.

Comment: insertion and deletion were last on the OP's list, and being integers can be optimized with calls to memcpy().

Comment: The "ordered" part is important, so I can't sort the data.

Comment: @Leonel ordered means sorted according to the ordering rules you specify

Comment: Probable he means "insertion order"

Answer (score 1):

I like balanced binary trees a lot. They are sometimes slower than hash tables or other structures, but they are much more predictable; they are generally `O(log n)` for all operations. I would suggest using a [Red-black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree) or an [AVL tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree).

Comment: hash table wouldn't keep the data ordered.

Comment: Oops, I didn't see the ordered part... I fixed it though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what language you're using, but if it's Java you can leverage [LinkedHashMap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) or a similar Collection. It's got all of the benefits of a List and a Map, provides constant time for most operations, and has the memory footprint of an elephant. :)

If you're not using Java, the idea of a LinkedHashMap is probably still suitable for a usable data structure for your problem.

Comment: How are you going to get a random element using LinkedHashMap?

Answer (score 1):

How to achieve 2 with RB-trees? We can make them count their children with every insert/delete operations. This doesn't make these operationis last significantly longer. Then getting down the tree to find the i-th element is possible in log n time. But I see no implementation of this method in java nor stl.

Answer (score 1):

Use a vector for the array access.

Use a map as a search index to the subscript into the vector.

- **given a subscript fetch the value** from the vector O(1)
- **given a key, use the map to find** the subscript of the value.  O(lnN)
- **insert a value**, push back on the vector O(1) amortized, insert the subscript into
  the map O(lnN)
- **delete a value**, delete from the map O(lnN)

Comment: This doesn't work for insertion and deletion at arbitrary indices.

Answer (score 0):

Howabout a Treemap? log(n) for the operations described.

Comment: Java TreeMap (assuming that's what you mean) does not support querying, inserting or erasing by index.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in .NET, then according to the MS docs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx

- SortedDictionary and SortedList both have O(log *n*) for retrieval
- SortedDictionary has O(log *n*) for insert and delete operations, whereas SortedList has O(*n*).

The two differ by memory usage and speed of insertion/removal.  SortedList uses less memory than SortedDictionary.  If the SortedList is populated all at once from sorted data, it's faster than SortedDictionary.  So it depends on the situation as to which is really the best for you.

Also, your argument for the Linked List is not really valid as it might be O(1) for the insert, but you have to traverse the list to find the insertion point, so it's really not.