# What data structure for O(1) random insertion/deletion and O(1) random access?

Tags: c, performance, data-structures

I don't know what data structure to use for this problem. I want the structure to have:

- Constant time insertion or deletion.
- Constant time retrieval by id.

The actual system is:

I've got a bunch of objects each with a unique id. My program will need to receive requests for an id and return the relevant object.

Whenever it receives a request I want it to: search the structure to see if it's there. If it is, return it. If it isn't, load it from the disk into memory (put it in the structure so that next time it is requested it doesn't have to use the disk) and then return it.

I'm using C.

Here's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174852/what-is-the-best-data-structure-container-for-fast-element-insertion-deletion-b) but I'm not sure how relevant it is.

Comment: I think you're not the first one who wants all-in-one cheap data structure :-)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890357/efficient-data-structure-for-fast-random-access-search-insertion-and-deletion

Comment: That's not exactly the same either.

Comment: Yeah, a "fast" instead of "O(1)" is requested there (and search is also requested).  Neither of these questions is going to get the exact solution, but you **will** accept **here** exactly the same answer that was accepted **there**.

Comment: Arrays either don't have O(1) lookup, or else don't have O(1) insertion, depending whether you reckon by index in the array (in which case no O(1) insert), or by some property of the object in the array (in which case no O(1) lookup). If the "unique id" lives in a small enough range that you can use it as the index and allocate a "big array of everything" up front, then in this case you could have O(1) read/write access by index, and you don't need insertion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A [Hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) might be a pretty good solution in your case -- even if it's not in O(1) when there's a colision : it's a quite efficient solution.

Comment: Be sure to look at several hash table implementations in order to find the best performance to your needs.

If you want to learn more, don't miss to read about Google's "BigTable". They have a great Hash Table implementation. (it's actually a database, but uses serveral Hash Table concepts, and a Hash Table as a index)

Comment: doesn't Hash Table access require using hash() function, this result in O(T{Hash(key)})

Answer (score 2):

The only structure that fits it is... C array.
 `SomeObject arr[MAX_NUM_OBJECTS]`
 handles this in fast and efficient way

Comment: Wait... how's your performance on deletion, when not at the end?

Comment: O(1) because the only way you can get O(1) on lookup by ID is when you can use the ID as array index - and then deletion is just setting the entry to null.

Comment: ++ @Michael Borgwardt: Right. In the case where the ID can be used as an array index, the identity function is a "perfect hash function". If the ID is bigger than this, you're back to normal hashing, which is also O(1) but can be slower by a sizeable constant bound.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just put them all in a file, mmap the file, and let the OS handle the caching?

Comment: That's a good point the only reason for not doing that is that it is memory inefficient in this case. The object I'm working with are 268 bytes each and a page of mem is 4KB.

Comment: OK, but reading 268 bytes off the disk is not necessarily going to be any faster than reading 4KB.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how much data and what the keys are. Hash tables work well for large amounts of data that would be difficult to compare (strings, complex data structures, ect). For smaller data sets with integer keys you can often get better performance with simple red-black trees. This is because good hash functions take time to execute.

In reality neither of those really meet what you're asking. O(1) access is only truly achievable in perfect hashes (and no hash is perfect) and arrays. Meanwhile O(1) insertion is only possible in queues, dequeues, stacks, linked lists, and perfect hashes (which again, no hash is perfect).

To give you a better answer we really need to know what you are trying to accomplish. Any more information on what you are using the data structure for would help