# Self-sorted data structure with random access

Tags: data-structures

I need to implement self-sorted data structure with random access. Any ideas?

Comment: Try a search engine first. Voting to close for lack of enthusiasm on OP's part to do basic homework.

Comment: Do not hurry. This is not such easy as look at first.

Comment: Here's one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890357/efficient-data-structure-for-fast-random-access-search-insertion-and-deletion

Comment: And yes, do point out what you tried, and what can't get to work.

Answer (score 1):

A self sorted data structure can be binary search trees. If you want a self sorted data structure and a self balanced one. AVL tree is the way to go. Retrieval time will be O(lgn) for random access.

Answer (score 0):

Maintaining a sorted list and accessing it arbitrarily requires at least O(lgN) / operation. So, look for [AVL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree), [red-black trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree), [treaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treap) or any other similar data structure and enrich them to support random indexing. I suggest [treaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treap) since they are the easiest to understand/implement.

One way to enrich the treap tree is to keep in each node the count of nodes in the subtree rooted at that node. You'll have to update the count when you modify the tree (eg: insertion/deletion).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too much involved lately with data structures implementation. Probably this answer is not an answer at all... you should see "Introduction to algorithms" written by Thomas Cormen. That book has many "recipes" with explanations about the inner workings of many data structures.
On the other hand you have to take into account how much time do you want to spend writing an algorithm, the size of the input and the if there is an actual necessity of an special kind of datastructure.

Answer (score 0):

I see one thing missing from the answers here, the Skiplist
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list

You get order automatically, there is a probabilistic element to search and creation.

Fits the question no worse than binary trees.

Answer (score -1):

Self sorting is a little bit to ambigious. First of all

**What kind of data structure?**

There are a lot of different data structures out there, such as:

- Linked list
- Double linked list
- Binary tree
- Hash set / map
- Stack
- Heap

And many more and each of them behave differently than others and have their benefits of course.

Now, not all of them could or should be self-sorting, such as the Stack, it would be weird if that one were self-sorting.

However, the Linked List and the Binary Tree could be self sorting, and for this you could sort it in different ways and on different times.

**For Linked Lists**

I would preffere [Insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) for this, you can read various good articles about this on both wikis and other places. I like the pasted link though. Look at it and try to understand the concept.

If you want to sort after it is inserted, i.e. on random times, well then you can just implement a sorting algororithm different than insertion sort maybe, [bubblesort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) or maybe [quicksort](http://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), I would avoid bubblesort though, it's a lot slower! But easier to gasp the mind around.

**Random Access**

Random is always something thats being discusses around so have a read about how to perform good randomization and you will be on your way, if you have a linked list and have a "getAt"-method, you could just randomize an index between 0 and n and get the item at that index.

Comment: I think alex is looking for a data structure that can do nth element very fast while allowing the list to be modified.

Comment: By random access I think the OP means "arbitrary access" - i.e. he can look up by the index.